# Pattern Replacement using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace `[cite:lamport94]` into `\cite{lamport94}` using a regular expression in C#.

```
String input = "how easy it is to create a well structured document within [cite:lamport94].  You should quickly be able to see."

String output = "how easy it is to create a well structured document within \cite{lamport94}.  You should quickly be able to see."
```

Comment: You always have one `[]` and one `:` in your string?

Comment: No there can be one or more occurrence of [cite:xyz]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you can use. It will capture any alphanumeric string inside square brackets with ":" delimiter:

```
 var input = "how easy it is to create a well structured document within [cite:lamport94].  You should quickly be able to see.";
 var rxReg = new Regex(@"\[(\w+):(\w+)]");
 var result = rxReg.Replace(input, @"\$1{$2}");
```

Output:

```
how easy it is to create a well structured document within \cite{lamport94}.  You should quickly be able to see.
```

BTW, if you have more than just `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters inside the brackets, you can extend `\w` to `[\w.:-]` (the pattern I prefer to match `mm.xxx`, or `xx-yy`, or  `xx:yyyy` strings. Add more if you need (mind that hyphen must stay at the end of the character class to stay a literal hyphen).

To only limit to `cite`, use it instead of first `\w`:

```
 var rxReg = new Regex(@"\[cite:(\w+)]");
 var result = rxReg.Replace(input, @"\cite{$1}");
```

Comment: @stribizhev I think you forgot to replace `$2` with `$1`.. welcome :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
\[(cite):(.*?)\]    //assuming you always have cite as common
```

And replace with

```
\$1{$2}
```

Comment: `\\\1{\2}` is not C#-compliant subsitution string.

Comment: @AnkanKumarGiri: You do not have to add a capturing group around `(cite)`, it worsens performance. You can use it directly in the replacement pattern. Please see my update for a regex with the `cite` used as a literal string in the regex. Also, if I did not mention the problem with the replacement string, this solution would not work at all for you.

Comment: @stribizhev .. capturing `cite` makes the replacement easy.. thats all.. and it wont `worsen` the performance.. since doesnot depend on string length.. and always takes `+2 steps only` (constant.. so no performance issues)

Comment: @stribizhev glad that you think so.. :)